# SqlBulkCopy does not store accented characters properly

Tags: sql-server-2008, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I am inserting French language text into nvarchar column in SQL server 2008. The French accented characters are not stored properly in the SQL DB.

```
string strData = "Accented chars- Les caractères accentués français ";

DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
dtTemp.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
dtTemp.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

DataRow dr = dtTemp.NewRow();
dr["ID"] = "100";
dr["Value"] = strData;
dtTemp.Rows.Add(dr);


strSQLCon = GetSQLConnectionString();
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strSQLCon))
{
    cn.Open();
    using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))
    {
        copy.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "ID");
        copy.ColumnMappings.Add("Value", "Value");

        copy.DestinationTableName = "MYTABLE";
        copy.WriteToServer(dtTemp);
    }
}
```

The French characters are not stored properly in SQL server data base. 
It works fine when i do a normal insert query. insert into MYTABLEvalues(1 , 'Accented chars- Les caractères accentués français')

Please let me know why it does not work with SQL Bulk copy class. Any settings need to be changed or C# code needs to be modified to store the non-English characters properly.

Comment: step into your code by breaking on dr["Value"] = strData; and verify that the data still has non-English characters? maybe encoding is wrong in the C# code somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am designing this table, **the collation for every column** is set to `French_CI_AS`, French culture, accent sensitive. **Every sql string type considered**. [image: french collation]

I am building a **typed dataset** for this table (not the purpose of this question).[image: typed dataset]

Sql **bulk** copy:

```
  var ds = new FrenchCharacters.FrenchDataSet();
  using (var destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(StackOverflow.Properties.Settings.Default.StackOverflowConnectionString))
      {
        destinationConnection.Open();
        //all French characters http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_orthography
        string[] sArray = new string[] { 
            "Àà, Ââ, Ææ, Ää"
            , "Çç"
            , "Îî, Ïï"
            , "Ôô, Œœ, Öö"
            , "Ùù, Ûû, Üü"
            , "Ÿÿ"
          };
        // open the connection
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection.ConnectionString))
        {
          bulkCopy.BatchSize = 500;
          bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 10000;
          bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "French";
          //
          // build data table to be written to the server
          // data table is now strongly-typed ds.French
          //
          for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
          {
            foreach (string s in sArray)
              ds.French.AddFrenchRow(s, s, s, s, s, s);                 
          }
          //
          bulkCopy.WriteToServer(ds.French);
        }
      }
```

result:[image]

**Notice no invalid entries whatever the sql char type!**.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code on the following table and it worked fine, at least on SQL Server 2012.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MYTABLE](
    [ID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your replies. The issue seems to occur while reading the csv file into data table before bulk insert.   I included the encoding parameter while reading the csv file. (Encoding.Default) and it loads the french text properly and it gets stored in SQL DB without any issues.

old code:
List lstData = File.ReadAllLines(stFile).ToList();

Working code:
List lstData = File.ReadAllLines(stFile, Encoding.Default).ToList();

thanks
Ashok